# Non-standard transposition

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to transpose lists of X values with lists of Y values.
In the form of:

```
X={{x1,x2,x3},{x11,x12,x13}} 
Y={{y1,y2,y3},{y11,y12,y13}}
```

In order to get lists of X and Y values in the form of:

```
{{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}},{{x11,y11},{x12,y12},{x13,y13}}}
```

If I use `Transpose[X, Y]` I get a permutation error.

Is it possible to use the `Transpose` command for such a task?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you may use the second argument like this:

```
Transpose[{X, Y}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

> `{{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, {{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}, {x13, y13}}}`

Answer (score 3):

Try `MapThread`

```
X={{x1,x2,x3},{x11,x12,x13}} 
Y={{y1,y2,y3},{y11,y12,y13}}

MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {X, Y}, 2]
(*{{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, {{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}, {x13, y13}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
Transpose[#] & /@ Transpose[{X, Y}]
```

> `{{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, {{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}, {x13, y13}}}`

Comment: No need pure function just use `Transpose /@ Transpose@{X, Y}`

Answer (score 1):

```
Flatten[{X, Y}, {{2}, {3}}]
```

> {{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, {{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}, {x13, y13}}}